# Send JSON to PHP MYSQL Server POST Method?

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am a beginner.
This is my json array : `["1","2","3","4"]`

How do i send this simple json array to php mysql server using volley or retrofit 2? 
Any example related to this would also help!

Please help me out guys!

Thanks in advance

Comment: check volley jsonarrayrequest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert it to String and send it to server, where you can again decode it to jsonArray and get the values.

Comment: Hey Wilson Christian, thank you so much. It was very helpful!